# How to pass data between 2 views using one controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

The below code contains 2 views and I want to get the data from index to user.

**JS code:**

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("MainController",function($scope,$window,$rootScope)
{
    $rootScope.loc={UserName:"",Pwd:""};
    $scope.name="";
    $scope.check=function()
    {
        $scope.name=$rootScope.loc.UserName;

        if(($rootScope.loc.UserName !="") && ($rootScope.loc.Pwd!=""))
        {
            alert($scope.name);
            $window.location = 'user.html'
        }
    }
});
```

**main.html**

```
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="loc.UserName">
Pwd: <input type="text" ng-model="loc.Pwd">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Award me" ng-click="check()">
```

**user.html**

```
<h1 id="honor" ng-controller="MainController">{{name}}!!!!</h1>
```

Comment: You can add your data in `$rootScope` and then use it in your application but using `$rootScope` is not advised, you should either use `controllerAs` or make use of a `service`

Answer (score 1):

Using **`$rootScope`** is not recommended, you can make use of angular **`service`** to do the same.

Create a service, that will hold  model variables.

```
angular.service("dataService", function() {
    this.value1 = "";  
});
```

Then you can reference that service in your controllers,

```
angular.controller("myCntrl1", function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.dataService = dataService;
});


angular.controller("myCntrl2", function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.dataService = dataService;
});
```

Comment: Downvoter write down the reason

Comment: Where will the check() function go ? In the service or controller 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

We can create a `service` to `set` and `get` the data between the controllers and then inject that service in the controller function where we want to use it.

**Service :**

```
app.service('setGetData', function() {
  var data = '';
    getData: function() { return data; },
    setData: function(requestData) { data = requestData; }
});
```

**Controllers :**

```
app.controller('myCtrl1', ['setGetData',function(setGetData) {

  // To set the data from the one controller
  var data = 'Hello World !!';  
  setGetData.setData(data);

}]);

app.controller('myCtrl2', ['setGetData',function(setGetData) {

  // To get the data from the another controller  
  var res = setGetData.getData();
  console.log(res); // Hello World !!

}]);
```

Here, we can see that `myCtrl1` is used for `setting` the data and `myCtrl2` is used for `getting` the data. So, we can share the data from one controller to another controller like this.